# SQL syntax is ok but php still throw error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

My sql query when I check manually in phpmyadmin works fine, but when I try to handle it through php mysql_query throw me a syntax error. How to solve this issue?

Error message:

```
Invalid query:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO scores( user_id ) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID( ))' at line 1 
Whole query:
INSERT INTO users (id_fb, name, first_name, last_name, email, link, first_login) 
VALUES ('1000001010101010', 'Bart Roza', 'Bart', 'Roza', 'lalalala@gmail.com','http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1000001010101010','2011-05-07 11:15:24'); 
INSERT INTO scores( user_id ) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID( ));
```

My php function:

```
public function createUser()
{
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users (id_fb, name, first_name, last_name, email, link, first_login) VALUES (" .
              "'" . $this->me['id'] . "', " .
              "'" . $this->me['name'] . "', " .
              "'" . $this->me['first_name'] . "', " .
              "'" . $this->me['last_name'] . "', " .
              "'" . $this->me['email'] . "'," .
              "'" . $this->me['link'] . "'," .
              "'" . $time . "'); " .
              "INSERT INTO scores( user_id ) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID( ));";

    $result = mysql_query($insert);
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $insert;
        die($message);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the solution!

Comment: If encountering mySQL query problems, always look at the final, generated query, not the PHP code. The PHP code is meaningless here

Comment: @Pekka: in this case - it is meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

Since `mysql_query` accepts only one query you need to split your query string into 2 separated queries and perform it with 2 `mysql_query` calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can not run multiple queries in once using [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function. you have to run these two queries with separate `mysql_query` call

> mysql_query() sends a unique query
>   (multiple queries are not supported)

Answer (score 0):

AS @zerkms and @Shakti said, mysql_query does not support multiple queries. If you want to use such functionality, consider migrating to mysqli. It supports multiple queries in a single packet by [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)